# Prove that $P(A \cup B') = 1 − P(B \cap A')$

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

I know that $P(A\cup B') = P(A) + P(B') - P(A\cap B')$ and $P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B')$ but still am unable to figure this out. Is there a way to rewrite $P(B ∩ A')$?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please edit this to include the [tag:self-study] tag.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint for using your original approach:**

Your first equation is relevant:

\begin{equation}
P(A\cup B') = P(A) + P(B') - P(A \cap B')
\end{equation}

Now use your second equation for $B$ as well as $A$

\begin{equation}
P(B) = P(B \cap A) +  P(B \cap A')
\end{equation}

Along with the simple fact that $P(B) + P(B') = 1$, this should be enough for you to prove the desired statement.

Comment: Hi thanks for that. So now I've simplified it down to P(B∩A') = - P(B∩A') but now i'm stuck because the right side is negative. Am I on the right track or am I completely off?
Is there a way I can rewrite 1−P(B∩A′)?

Comment: If you actually simplified down to $P(B\cap A') = - P(B\cap A')$ then you have effectively proven that $P(B \cap A') = 0$... which is not sensible. I would try again. In the first equation, (i) replace $P(B')$ with $1-P(B)$ and (ii) replace $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ with the other thing. You'll get a bunch of cancellations and should end up with the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A \cup C) = 1 - P(A^* \cap C^*)$.
Set $C = B^*$.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(A\cup B') = 1-P\left((A\cup B')'\right) = 1-P\left(A'\cap B\right)$$ as $(A\cup B')' = (A'\cap B)$.